# A counterexample to show that the following set does not form a semigroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, semigroups, monoid

Let $A = $ { $f:\mathbb Z$ $\to \mathbb Z$| the cardinality of set {$x \in \mathbb Z$ | $f(x) = x$} is finite}.

I have to prove or disprove that the set $A$ forms a semigroup/monoid under function composition.

I can easily see that $A$ does not form monoid because the identity function does not exist in $A$. I am trying to look for an example to disprove that $A$ forms a semigroup. Does the following work?

Let $f(x) = x +1 $ and $h(x) = x-1 \in A\ \forall x \in \mathbb Z$. Then, we can see that {$x$ $\in$ $\mathbb Z$ | $f(x) = x$} is finite because no element gets mapped to itself, hence it is an empty set, and similar for {$x$ $\in$ $\mathbb Z$ | $h(x) = x$}, which is also an empty set. But, $f(g(x)) = x$ $\forall$ $x \in \mathbb Z$. Hence, the set {$x$ $\in$ $\mathbb Z$ | $h(f(x)) = x$} is infinite and hence, closure is not satisfied. Can anyone check my work, please?

Comment: This looks good to me.

Comment: Looks correct to me too.

Comment: @freakish Your claim about complements of submonoids not being submonoids is not true. The issues is that the complement may have a *new* identity. For example, consider $\{0, 1\}$ under multiplication. This is a monoid, with $1$ being the identity. However, both $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$ are monoids in their own right. [I guess you could define require a submonoid to have the same identity element as the monoid, rather than just a subsemigroup which is a monoid. However, it is the latter definition which the post is showing.]

Comment: @freakish You said "rarely" for semigroups, but "never" for monoids.